# Cycles rendering mode crashes the entire program AMD OpenCL

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, gpu, drivers

I never had this problem before, I recently came back to Blender and I'm doing the Donut series by Andrew Price, everything was working fine and I got midway but from one day to another, the entire program freezes and crashes or bugs out when I switch to render view mode in viewport or rendering with f12. I use a AMD RX 570 8gb, as I said everything worked fine, I already tried different drivers for my card, older and newer, I play a lot of games and there aren't problems there. I already switched to 2.91 version of Blender, and 2.9, Idk what else to do, I cleanly uninstalled my graphic drivers with DDU even, but it's the same, the program now gives an error with 2.91 tho, it says: "Split kernel error: failed to load kernel_indirect_background". The program is not frozen but I can only see the orange outlines of my objects if selected, there's nothing else in the viewport. Please help me, I'm really eager to learn to use this program again, and it's my favorite one tbh. I use Windows 10 Pro latest update.

Comment: If it was working before, then go back to the version that worked. There might be a conflict with that specific GPU (AMD's have a long history of problems with blender).

Comment: I mean it's still installed, the version is 2.9, I just downloaded the 2.91 as a portable version and I opened the same file in there, so it gave me the Split Kernel error. Version 2.9.0 doesnt give an error but the rendering is all glitched, there's straight lines in the inferior left part, and blue and red pixels appeared which weren't there before, I followed everything like the tutorial says, I didn't change anything as far as I checked.

Answer (score 1):

Posted this in an AMD forum Users Post:

Re: In 2021,Why AMD GPU Still Sucks On Cycles?!

I think I might have found a so-called hack to get the 'Indirect_Background' one to work.

1. Start with initial default cube. Mainly so that Blender will recover faster.
2. Add a HDRI (don't really know if you have to).
3. Switch from 'Solid' view to 'Mat Preview' then switch to 'Render' view. Now I think it does start to hang, but immediately switch back to 'Mat View' and wait for it to clear its self up. Then switch back to 'Render' view.
4. Hit F10 while still in 'Viewport' (may not have to do this, but was in 'Mat Preview').
5. Go to Render tab and watch the magic happen (hopefully).

I don't think I've forgotten anything. You can then open another file and everything should still work. Even on start up.

*** Updated to Adrenaline 21.4.1, repeated what's above and it still works ***

[image]

Comment: Fantastic, going to mat preview THEN render worked, thank you so much

Comment: I'm so happy it worked for you (really).